# Install Faenza icons on libreoffice 3.5 toolbar

Tags: libreoffice, icons, faenza

According to [a WEB UPD8 post](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/faenza-icons-for-libreoffice-toolbar.html) from july 2011, it is possible to install Faenza-styled icons on LibreOffice toolbar.

I can't install Faenza the traditional way on LO 3.5 (i.e., changing the toolbar icons from Crystal or Tango from inside the application's "Options" menu) and now those icons are broken.

Faenza was already installed but the update removed everything.

Comment: How did you install Faenza for older LibreOffice versions??

Comment: thanks for Your advice - but I have to make "my own" package include small icons... I am using it on mac and for it I need a small icons. So if You want I send You may .zip file. Michal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update manager, today updated LO to 3.5 also here (Ubuntu 11.04). As I was using same icon theme I noticed same issue.

Just copying faenza archive over /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images_crystal.zip was not enough. Comparing icon theme archives from LO 3.5 with faenza set, revealed two possible misplacements:

```
res/commanimagelist -> cmd
vlc/source/src      -> vlc/res
```

I expect that first one was responsible for this issues, although I changed both: [download link (3.6 MB)](http://hotfile.com/dl/148606485/e3b80bd/images_faenza.zip.html)

So after downloading this archive place it as /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images_crystal.zip and then setting view to crystal should show faenza icons again :)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: LibreOffice now looks great. Thank you very much!

Comment: do you know how to make this work on libreoffice and 12.04?

Comment: i meant libreoffice-4.0/ubuntu-12.04

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't bring back Faenza icons to LibreOffice (if they had been there), but this should fix its icons:

You could try to (re)install the usual icon theme [libreoffice-style-human](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libreoffice-style-human)[image: Install libreoffice-style-human] (click this link to do so) and choose it in *Settings* as follows:

Start LibreOffice and open the appropriate settings Dialog:

[image: start lo]

[image: open options]

Choose the correct icon theme:

[image: options]

Does this help?

Comment: I have it this way but now I want to install faenza

Comment: AFAIK there are no Faenza icons for LibreOffice - so I wonder how you installed them for LibreOffice 3.4 as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Something like this http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/faenza-icons-for-libreoffice-toolbar.html the floder was different but it worked.

Comment: So you should find out where the icons are stored, i.e. `locate images_human.zip` if you installed `libreoffice-style-human`. Then you should install a second icon theme you don't want to use, i.e. `libreoffice-style-crystal`. You should go to the icon folder (start Nautilus as sudo: `sudo nautilus`), backup the crystal icon theme, i.e. rename it to *images_crystal.orig.zip*, move the zip-file [downloaded here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=143474) to this forlder and name it *images_crystal.zip*. Then choose *Crystal* in LibreOffice. Don't know if this works in 3.5, though.

Comment: does not work D: that's the problem

Comment: *What's* the problem? If you don't describe **exactly** what doesn't work it's relatively difficult to help you. What did you try?

Comment: @Jakob: Obviously problem is that procedure you described is relevant for 3.4 and it worked for `user46035` when he had 3.4 With 3.5 it doesn't work any more for him/her. Does it work for you? Can you use Faenza set in 3.5?

Comment: @user46035: You may ask your question at Andrew's blog. I'm sure you'll get reply if Andrew knows. I don't have 3.5 to try to help